# How to get customer details from a file?

Tags: python

I am new to Python but trying to create a Bank account system. I did create the BankAccount class and the customer records but how do I put the two codes together

Comment: `with open("nameofthefile.ext", "r") as f:`

Comment: Creating objects in one class in another might be an approach. Sharing current code base will help to answer.

Comment: have you tried to find a tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

May be helpful to you:
Each account is an instance of the BankAccount class you created, and each of the account's information corresponds to each of the properties in the BankAccount class.
You can initialize each instance via the **init** method after reading the account information from the file.